# Adding thousands items to a table widget without freezing the window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qthread, qtablewidget

I have a table widget where I am adding thousands of rows. The problem is that every time I add a row, it updates the window causing it to take around 30 seconds for the entire thing to finish, all while the window is completely unresponsive. One small solution that I found was the hide the table, add all of the rows, then show the table, which drastically reduces the amount of the time the window is unresponsive, but I am wondering if there is a way add rows to a table without freezing the window at all and seeing the rows being added individually. I have looked at other answers that use QThread, but those haven't worked for me because those solutions still have the main thread adding rows(which takes the most time) to the table causing the main window to still be unresponsive

Example code:

```py
import sys
from time import time
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QPushButton, QHeaderView, QApplication, QMainWindow

class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(1600, 900)

        self.table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.table.setFixedSize(1600, 900)
        self.table.setColumnCount(5)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(3, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(4, QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.show()

        self.populate_table()

    def populate_table(self):
        start = time()
        # self.table.hide()
        for i in range(2000):
            row = self.table.rowCount()
            self.table.insertRow(row)
            for i_ in range(5):
                item = QPushButton("filler")
                self.table.setCellWidget(row, i_, item)
        print(f"took {time() - start} seconds")
        self.table.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    Gui = window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Threading is certainly not a solution, since the problem here is only about UI management (which can only happen in the main thread). The most important questions are: 1. Do you actually need to set buttons as item widgets for each row? Setting widgets on item views can become a performance issue for very large models, and you might prefer a custom delegate instead. 2. Is the row count known before starting the procedure? Because if that's so, some improvement might come by setting the new rowCount just *once* (before the first for cycle) instead of adding one row for each cycle.

Comment: If you have sorting turned on, that can make update speeds in large tables very slow. Disabling sorting before you do the add and then re-enabling it can help. 
The above comment on not adding widgets is also pertinent.
Lastly, if performance is really important, consider using a QTableView with a custom model instead of a QTableWidget. You can really optimize performance a lot more in that case and I've seen substantial improvement when moving large data-sets into a MVC instead of using the all-in-one Widgets

Comment: In my actual GUI, I am not using push buttons, but instead have a variety of widgets for each row. I just thought it would be easier for the example if I simply did it with push buttons. Could you please explain what you mean by a custom model? The row count is known before, so I will try that when I have a chance.

Comment: I will definitely look into using a QTableView when I have time, but that is completely new to me. I don't think disabling sorting will change the time that much, but I will try it. Could you explain what MVC is?